The definition of RPG
I have Rpg program. Is there any one to explain this code. I have input file in this program. the out file contains some data which does not exist in input data, for instance, ACCS, ACCT,ACC11. I want to understand , where they located in input?
01010H
01050FINPUT   IP  F9000  90            DISK30
01070FOUT     O   F9000  90            DISK30
01070FSYS008  O   F 132 132     OF    LPRINTER
01050FDISPFIL D   F     120            CONSOLE
02010E                    RK1         9  1 0 RK2     1 0
02010E                    RK3         9  3 0 RK4     1
01070LSYS008    101 5612
07010IINPUT   NS  02
07022I                                        1   5 BR
07022I                                        6   80GR00
07022I                                        9  180ACC00
07022I                                       19  280ACCS
07022I                                       29  380ACCT
07022I                                       39  480ACC11
07022I                                       49  68 TABN00
07022I                                       71  75 CBI1
07022I                                       76  80 CBI2
07022I                                       71  85 CBI3
07022I                                       86  90 CBI4
07030I                                        1  90 REC1
01020IDATEU       DS                              8
03020I                                        1   2 DAYU
03020I                                        3   3 SEP1
03020I                                        4   5 MONTHU
03020I                                        6   6 SEP2
03020I                                        7   8 YEARU
04050C****************************************************
04050C  N20                EXSR Y2K
04050C****************************************************
06100C  N80                SETON                     80
04060C      66             GOTO AAA
05030C           CCC       TAG
05030C                     SETOF                     62
05040C  N66                MOVEL'BRANCH'  A10    13
05050C  N66                MOVE 'LIMIT '  A10
05060C  N66                MOVEL'FORMAT=' A12    14
05070C  N66                MOVE 'BBBBB E' A12
05070C  N66                MOVELA12       A16    18
05070C  N66                MOVE 'EEEE'    A16
05080C  N66                MOVELA10       A14    31
05090C  N66                MOVE A16       A14
05090C  N66                MOVEL'        'A56    24
05090C  N66                MOVEL'FOR LIST'A66    16
05090C  N66                MOVE '  SGB26B'A66
05090C  N66                MOVE A66       A56
05090C  N66                MOVELA14       A45    55
05090C  N66                MOVE A56       A45
05110C  N66                MOVE '       ' A15    11
05110C  N66                MOVEL'    '    A15
05130C  N66      A45       DSPLYDISPFIL   A15
05140C  N66                MOVELA15       FROM    5
05150C  N66                MOVE A15       TO      5
05160C  N66      FROM      COMP '99999'                  70
05170C  N66 70   TO        COMP '99999'                  71
05170C  N66 70 71          SETON                         LR
05180C*     71             GOTO END1
06010C  N66      FROM      COMP TO                   H1
06020C   H1                MOVEL'REFER   'A10
06030C   H1                MOVE '  H1    'A10
06040C   H1                DSPLYDISPFIL   A10
06050C   H1                GOTO CCC
06100C  N66                SETON                     66
06070C           AAA       TAG
06080C   02                SETOF                     6562
06080C   02      BR        COMP FROM                 63  63
06090C   02 63   BR        COMP TO                   626464
06100C   02 63 64          SETON                     65
06102C   02 62             SETOF                     66
06104C   02 62             GOTO CCC
06080C   02      GR00      COMP 520                      75
06080C   02N75   GR00      COMP 550                      75
06070C           END1      TAG
04050C****************************************************
04050C****************************************************
07030CSR         Y2K       BEGSR
04050CSR                   CALL 'DATT2'                10
04050CSR                   PARM           DATEU
07030CSR                   SETON                       20
07030CSR                   MOVE 'Z'       SEP1
07030CSR                   MOVE 'Z'       SEP2
07030CSR                   ENDSR
04050C****************************************************
24010OSYS008  H 1101  N80
24010O       OR        OF
24020O                                   20 ' #= 13  S.-UX-/A.'
24020O                         PAGE  Z   28
24020O                                   33 'V%JC'
24020O                         YEARU     38
24020O                                   39 'Z'
24020O                         MONTHU    41
24020O                                   42 'Z'
24020O                         DAYU      44
24020O                                   51 '>X''<|('
24020O                                   75 'V#B V#<J|A.'
24020O                                   94 'Y<W(<A%V''<RBV#U#%R'
24020O                                  130 'V(HB'
24020O                         BR       125
30220O        H 11    N80
24010O       OR        OF
31040O*                                 132 'V(HB#M'
31040O                                  124 ':(<A%VU''N'
31040O                                  105 'VU''N''AV''<RB'
31080O                                   75 'GU''BV''<RB'
31080O                                   50 'S<X<+V''<RB'
31080O                                   36 'V#BV#<J|A.SX''?.'
31080O                                    5 '#.#H|'
30220O        H  1    N80
24010O       OR        OF
31040O*                                 132 '------'
31040O                                  124 '---------'
31040O                                  105 '-----------'
31080O                                   75 '-----------'
31080O                                   50 '---------'
31080O                                   36 '-----------'
31080O                                    5 '-----'
30220O        D 11     02 65N75
31040O*                        BRN      130 '0    '
31040O                         GR00     120
31040O                         ACC00    105
31040O                         ACCS      75 '0    -  -   '
31040O                         ACCT      50 '0    -  -   '
31040O                         ACC11     36 '0    -  -   '
31040O                         TABN00    25
31080O*                        CONT       4
31080O*                24                 3 '24'
31080O*               N24                 3 'N24'
24010OOUT     D        02 65N75
24020O                         REC1      90

I have to know how we can produce output file from input file?

Could you put and INPUT record, corresponding OUTPUT record and tell us what do you have and what expected?

TLDR; this program prompts for a starting line number and an ending line number, and prints all the records in the input where BR is between the starting and ending line numbers entered by the user. Records where GR00 = 520 or 550 are not printed. It also writes the records printed to an disk file named OUT.

This is very old RPG, maybe RPG II, possibly from a real S36. It uses the RPG cycle so some things just happen, in a well defined manner. I would not expect it to compile without some modification on a modern IBM midrange, not even on an AS/400 (hasn't been sold since 1990's). The tip-offs are the device type DISK30 which is not valid on AS400 and later. The L spec is invalid for AS/400, and the file type D on DISPFIL is also invalid.
I've never used an L spec, so I don't know what that is for, and I don't really know how the CONSOLE device works as I have never used that either. So I can't really tell you how to make this compile on modern hardware.
None the less, there are some things I can tell you about it. The fields you asked about are defined for the input record. I know this because the INPUT record format is program defined.
Here is the definition of the input record:
07010IINPUT   NS  02
07022I                                        1   5 BR
07022I                                        6   80GR00
07022I                                        9  180ACC00
07022I                                       19  280ACCS
07022I                                       29  380ACCT
07022I                                       39  480ACC11
07022I                                       49  68 TABN00
07022I                                       71  75 CBI1
07022I                                       76  80 CBI2
07022I                                       71  85 CBI3
07022I                                       86  90 CBI4
07030I                                        1  90 REC1    

The first line names the file, and an indicator (boolean) to turn on (set true) when a record is read. The rest of the lines are fields in the record format. The numbers tell the location and length of the field in the record as a from and to position. Some like GR00 have an extra 0 that the others do not have. This extra 0 is the number of decimal positions, indicating the field is numeric vs. character, and also in this case the numeric format is Zoned decimal meaning the numbers are stored in memory one digit per byte with an implied decimal point. These would appear in a memory dump like 12345, or a hex dump like F1 F2 F3 F4 F5. Also notice that field on the last line REC1 appears to overlap the others since it's from position is 1 and it's to position is 90. This is perfectly legal in RPG.
Then there is some date stuff that is used to put what I guess is the current date in the report header. At least that is the only place the fields are used.
Following that is some code to prompt for from and to lines:
06100C  N80                SETON                     80
04060C      66             GOTO AAA
05030C           CCC       TAG
05030C                     SETOF                     62
05040C  N66                MOVEL'BRANCH'  A10    13
05050C  N66                MOVE 'LIMIT '  A10
05060C  N66                MOVEL'FORMAT=' A12    14
05070C  N66                MOVE 'BBBBB E' A12
05070C  N66                MOVELA12       A16    18
05070C  N66                MOVE 'EEEE'    A16
05080C  N66                MOVELA10       A14    31
05090C  N66                MOVE A16       A14
05090C  N66                MOVEL'        'A56    24
05090C  N66                MOVEL'FOR LIST'A66    16
05090C  N66                MOVE '  SGB26B'A66
05090C  N66                MOVE A66       A56
05090C  N66                MOVELA14       A45    55
05090C  N66                MOVE A56       A45
05110C  N66                MOVE '       ' A15    11
05110C  N66                MOVEL'    '    A15
05130C  N66      A45       DSPLYDISPFIL   A15
05140C  N66                MOVELA15       FROM    5
05150C  N66                MOVE A15       TO      5
05160C  N66      FROM      COMP '99999'                  70
05170C  N66 70   TO        COMP '99999'                  71
05170C  N66 70 71          SETON                         LR
05180C*     71             GOTO END1
06010C  N66      FROM      COMP TO                   H1
06020C   H1                MOVEL'REFER   'A10
06030C   H1                MOVE '  H1    'A10
06040C   H1                DSPLYDISPFIL   A10
06050C   H1                GOTO CCC
06100C  N66                SETON                     66
06070C           AAA       TAG

This code prompts for beginning and ending line numbers, I suspect that BR contains the line number in the input file, and returns it to the program in variables FROM and TO. If both FROM and TO are 99999, then the program ends, if FROM is greater than TO the program displays an error message and tries again.
Finally the bit you are interested in:
06080C   02                SETOF                     6562
06080C   02      BR        COMP FROM                 63  63
06090C   02 63   BR        COMP TO                   626464
06100C   02 63 64          SETON                     65
06102C   02 62             SETOF                     66
06104C   02 62             GOTO CCC
06080C   02      GR00      COMP 520                      75
06080C   02N75   GR00      COMP 550                      75
06070C           END1      TAG

Remember I said indicator 02 was turned on for each record read, these lines are only going to be used when a record is read (when 02 is on) first line sets off some more indicators 62 and 65. Next line compares BR to FROM and turns on indicator 63 if BR >= FROM. Next line compares BR to TO and turns on indicator 64 if BR is <= TO. If BR > TO, indicator 62 is turned on. Next turn on indicator 65 if both indicators 63 and 64 are turned on. This will happen when FROM <= BR <= TO. If indicator 62 is on after this, we set off indicator 66 and go back to the prompt code.
Notice the prompt code is conditioned by the 66 indicator. It only runs when indicator 66 is off.
There is also some code that filters out input lines where the field GR00 = 520 or 550.
Next comes a little more date code and header information for the report. Then these two output specifications:
30220O        D 11     02 65N75
31040O*                        BRN      130 '0    '
31040O                         GR00     120
31040O                         ACC00    105
31040O                         ACCS      75 '0    -  -   '
31040O                         ACCT      50 '0    -  -   '
31040O                         ACC11     36 '0    -  -   '
31040O                         TABN00    25
31080O*                        CONT       4
31080O*                24                 3 '24'
31080O*               N24                 3 'N24'
24010OOUT     D        02 65N75
24020O                         REC1      90

The first one is part of SYS008 the second one is for file OUT (this is a disk file).The details print for each record that is read. These lines are written to thier respective files when indicator 65 is on, and indicator 75 is off. There is no calculation on the fields, they are just read from input, and written to output. The disk file gets the whole record, the print file gets selected fields, specifically: GR00, ACC00, ACCS, ACCT, ACC11, and TABN00.

This could be a version of Control Data Corp RPG II, DISK30 is consistent with devices listed in the CDC manual, though not specifically mentioned, and that dialect has the File Type D for display files, but the L Spec is still not right according to the CDC RPG II manual I looked at.

In the input,
ACCS is a number from position 19 to 28 with no decimal places in the input , so 10,0
ACCT is a number from position 29 to 38 with no decimal places in the input , so 10,0
ACC11 is a number from position 39 to 48 with no decimal places in the input , so 10,0
as shown by,
07022I                                       19  280ACCS
07022I                                       29  380ACCT
07022I                                       39  480ACC11

in the source.
When viewing the source press F4 on any line to see the column-based code broken out. You can then press F4 on any of the columns in the line for help on it.
The first line with INPUT in it has a P. This means INPUT is a primary file. A primary file is read through by the program.
As jmarkmurphy says, the next line in the source with INPUT in it is the internal definition of file INPUT in the program and because of the 02, indicator 02 is seton when a record is read.
Hope that helps
